# TypeScript compiler crash: publicMembers is null or undefined

Tags: typescript

The code presented below compiles and executes without error in its current form -- however, as soon as the type declaration of 'getNextAsyncTasks' on line 19 is uncommented the compiler crashes with the following errors:

1. Internal error: Unable to get value of the property 'publicMembers': object is null or undefined
2. Internal error: IntelliSense features are disabled. Try making edits to source files to restore a valid compilation state.
3. Unable to get value of the property 'publicMembers': object is null or undefined
4. The command ""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\TypeScript\0.8.0.0\tsc" ... " exited with code 1.

While I know how to avoid it in this particular case, the error keeps occurring silently as I work on other areas of my code base. It can be quite hard to debug since by the time I notice it happened I have often made a decent amount of changes and have no hints at where the problem might be coming from this time around.

Ideally, I'd appreciate if someone could let me know what causes this crash to happen so I can have a better idea of how to avoid it / work around it.

```
module abstract {
    export interface ICallback {
        (...args: any[]): any;
    }
    export interface IAsyncOp {
        (callback: ICallback): any;
    }
}

export class Chain {
    task : abstract.IAsyncOp;

    constructor(...tasks : abstract.IAsyncOp[]) {
        if (tasks.length === 1)     this.task = tasks[0];
        else if (tasks.length > 1)  this.task = cb => this.sync(() => cb.apply(null, arguments), tasks);
        else                        this.task = cb => cb();
    }

    next(getNextAsyncTasks /*: (...args: any[]) => abstract.IAsyncOp*/) {
        return new Chain(
            (cb: abstract.ICallback) =>
                this.task(
                    () => getNextAsyncTasks.apply(null, arguments)(cb);
                )
        );
    }

    last(cb : abstract.ICallback) {
        this.task(cb);
    }

    sync(cb: (...resultArgs: IArguments[]) => void, tasks: abstract.IAsyncOp[]) {
        var resultArgs : IArguments[] = [], done = 0;

        var getCb = (i) => {
            return () => {
                resultArgs[i] = arguments;
                done++;

                if (done === tasks.length) cb.apply(null, resultArgs);
            }
        };

        for (var i = 0, op; op = tasks[i]; i++) op(getCb(i));
    }
}

// use example
new Chain( cb => setTimeout(() => cb("foo"), 60)
         , cb => setTimeout(() => cb("bar"), 10)
         ).next((op1, op2) => { console.log(op1, op2)
                              ; return cb => setTimeout(() => cb(op1[0], op2[0]), 120)
                              }
         ).next((foo, bar) => { console.log(foo, bar)
                              ; return cb => setTimeout(() => cb(foo, bar, "baz"), 30)
                              }
         ).last((foo, bar, baz) => console.log(foo, bar, baz));
```

EDIT: Updated 'next' so the type signature of the param would always be correct.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a compiler bug and I'd file a report [here](http://typescript.codeplex.com/WorkItem/Create?ProjectName=typescript). I tried a number of things to work around it, none of which worked.  It's interesting because the crash doesn't actually manifest until you try to use it in your example.

Comment: Reported the crash, link for reference: http://typescript.codeplex.com/workitem/286